# Looping over results from query in blade template laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to run a foreach loop over an array of data coming back from a query in my controller in my blade template. I keep getting an error saying 'Undefined offset: 1' no matter how I try. If I simply print out `{{$reminders[0]['name']}}` it shows me what I would expect, but for some reason it is not having the foreach loop.

Here is a print out of one what I am getting back from my query in the log (the real array obviously has more values):

```
array ( 0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'user_id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Bob McTest',
    'content' => 'Testing, testing',
    'start_date' => NULL,
    'end_date' => NULL,
    'monthly' => NULL,
    'daily' => NULL,
    'created_at' => '2020-06-07T20:54:30.000000Z',
    'updated_at' => '2020-06-07T20:54:30.000000Z',
  ))
```

I have been trying different varieties of this, since this is what I am ultimately trying to accomplish:

```
@foreach $reminders as $reminder 
    {{$reminder['name']}}
@endforeach
```

I'm hoping this is something simple that I am just missing after a long day. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The foreach you show in your question gives you an undefined index 1? In other words, the undefined offset 1 is saying that you don't have data at the index 1. Try maybe visualizing your data with ```@dd($reminders)``` to have a look at your array.

Comment: @ettdro I tried adding that to see if it did look different from what I have been writing to the log and gave an example of in my question, but no dice. My array has ten items, so the error doesn't really make sense - also I am not directly calling the index of 1 in my foreach loop so I'm confused that it would be complaining about it anyway. I'm stumped!

Comment: Have you tried ```$reminders[1]['name']```?

Comment: @ettdro yes, it prints out the correct data for that index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns it out was just a syntax error, I was forgetting the () in the foreach loop *facepalm* Thanks for taking a look!